# SP2010-workflows is not visible in SharePoint online/CSOM?

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, csom

Can anyone confirm that SP2010-workflows is not "visible" in SharePoint online/CSOM.

My observations are that when I associate a 2010-WF, created in SPD, with a list I can not see it using for example

```
workflowSubscriptionService.EnumerateSubscriptionsByList()
```

But it does find the WF-association if I create a SP2013-WF.

My problem is that I have a legacy-WF that is modified from aSP2010-approval WF.

[This question](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/08efbb5b-b47b-4574-8280-64f2ef7c04dc/sharepoint-2010-workflow-and-csom-on-sharepoint-online?forum=SP2016) seems to imply that there is something ghost like with SP2010-WF:s in SP Online /Csom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using Workflow services API for get all workflow instances using JSOM or CSOM.

Actually, Workflow Services API included in SharePoint 2013.

SharePoint 2013 supports two types of workflows: old WF3 workflows (aka SharePoint 2010 Workflows) and new WF4 workflows (aka SharePoint 2013 Workflows). Workflow Service API is supposed to work primarily with the new WF4 workflows, but also contains some limited amount of methods for working with the old WF3 workflows.

It might be possible method which is used by you is not supported in SharePoint 2010.

Comment: Yes, Csom... So you are saying that I cant work with SP2010-WFs in SP Online +CSOM?

Comment: Yes, some of the methods are not supported for SP2010-WFs.

Comment: Ok, thanks :), this means I can drop this and try another way